# How to prevent client side caching of streamed data

Tags: angular, caching, server, stream, client

I can stream data from my server to a client, but it seems when I refresh to page it has cached the previously streamed audio and holding it like it's a file to which I can hit play  again and again. I need to use incognito to prevent it from thinking I sent it a file and remove the cache each time.

How do I tell the client that I am streaming and do not cache the information when the page is refreshed, all previously sent data should be ignored?

Answer (score 1):

You could set cache-controls to no-cache

Comment: http has a way (in the request) to specify cache time. @memeKing

Comment: please see the following url: @memeKing

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Comment: Changing the cache-control to "no-cache" solved my problem. I think you should edit your answer to display that and not the force caching of files to 1ms. Thanks though.

Comment: That is better in only one way: the client never tries to even cache the file.